# How to convert inline imports-loader to configuration imports-loader?

Tags: webpack, imports-loader

I'm attempting to introduce webpack for a legacy SPA. I'm in a very similar position to the author of [this](https://medium.com/@drgenejones/using-webpack-with-legacy-angular-spas-exposing-global-variables-to-child-modules-599e32f373c9) article, where I've adapted their code to webpack v4.

The application needs myApp defined globally, so I've exposed `myApp` like so:

**app.js**

```js
export var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './client/entryPoint.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /app\.js$/,
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: {
                    exposes: {
                        globalName: 'entry'
                    },
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

This works perfectly to recursively "inject" that global variable by adding some additional code:

**entryPoint.js**

```js
function importAll (r) {
    r.keys().forEach(function(file) {
        if (!file.includes('app.js')) {
            r(file);
        }
    });
}
importAll(require.context("imports-loader?additionalCode=var%20myApp%20=%20entry.myApp;!./app/", true, /.*\.js/));
```

This doesn't work defining it in the `webpack.config.js`:

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './client/entryPoint.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(app\.js|entryPoint\.js|node_modules)/,
                loader: 'imports-loader',
                options: {
                    additionalCode: 'var myApp = entry.myApp;'
                }

            },
            {
                test: /app\.js$/,
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: {
                    exposes: {
                        globalName: 'entry'
                    },
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

Inpecting the bundle, webpack hasn't added added the `additionalCode`  as it did when using the inline imports-loaders.

Any pointers to where the translation to configuration has gone awry?

EDIT 10/08/2020

Here's the structure of my app:

```
.
├── client
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   ├── about.html
│   │   │   └── about.js
│   │   ├── landing.html
│   │   └── landing.js
│   ├── index.html
│   └── entryPoint.js
├── dist...
├── package.json
├── node_modules...
└── webpack.config.js
```

The angular controllers expect myApp to be defined like so, e.g.:

**landing.js**

```js
myApp.controller('LandingCtrl', function($http){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is all the code that consumes `myApp` is in your respository? Can I suggest an alternative solution with `exports-loader` and `import-loader`? This is the way shim is configured in webpack 4

Comment: Yes please, open to alternative solutions, not particularly attached to this solution. I've clarified the structure of the app in the question if that helps